# Refreshing an aspx page on Radio Button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an a text box and a button I want to enable /disable upon radio button checked

```
protected void chkBookActive_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    txtCourseTitle.Text = " no input required"
    txtCourseTitle.Enabled = false;
    btnSearch.Enabled = true;
}
```

I've got all of this I just need it to take place on page when the button is checked. Nothing happens and I believe the checkChanged event should update automatically? but it doesn't do anything? Super easy to anyone versed in c#/asp.net

Comment: Are you just looking to set `AutoPostBack="true"` on the `CheckBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set check box property to

```
AutoPostBack = "true"
```

Comment: wow I'm an idiot 100% forgot to check for that.. Thanks for letting me know how spacey I can be!